# move label with text on that changes dynamically flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i'm just starting to learn flash and as3, 
i need to send to a flash movie text using javascript and the text will move around.

first i created a label that get text from javascript

the next thing i want to do is move the label around, i think i might be missing something but dont know what.

i tried using motion tween but the label refuse to move for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the TextField a name instance, for example "myDinamicText".

Donwload TweenLite/TweenMax from greensock (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) and then simply write something like this

```
 TweenLite.to (myDinamicText, 0.5, {x:100, y:100});
```

where 0.5 is the tweening duration and the others variables are the destination coordinates.

EDIT:
if you want to use the Tween Class, just write:

```
 var myTween:Tween = new Tween(my_box, "x", 40, 300, 5, true);
```

you can have a look here for a tutorial on how to use it:
[AS3 Tween Class](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/)

Comment: tnx for your answer but is using an external lib is the best solution?

Comment: Believe me, TweenLite/TweenMax is one of the best tween library out there. Everyone I know use it, it's simply beatiful and easy. But I can edit my answer if you want to use the Tween Class....

Comment: just tested it and its quite easy to use, can i change the size of the element when motion is done?

Comment: Yes, just write TweenLite.to (myDinamicText, 1, {scaleX:2, scaleY:2}); If the text disappears is because you haven't embedded it, remember to do it. Then test the easing curves, they're awesome too

Comment: tnx a lot!!! i will adopt this solution, but is there a reason why the regular tween isnt working? something to do with the fact that label is a UI component?